# NextJS 13 "A required parameter was not provided as a string in generateStaticParams"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, next.js13

[I am upgrading my current NextJS site to the latest version of NextJS 13 with the `app` directory and using `generateStaticParams`, I keep getting the following error when migrating my `getStaticPaths` to the new `app` directory page, I am using GraphQL:

`Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as a string in generateStaticParams for /[slug]`

I've consoled the returns and it seems to be returning the correct object with strings, not sure what I am missing.

```
// app/[slug]/page.tsx

export async function generateStaticParams() {
    const { data } = await client.query({
        query: gql`
            query getSlugs {
                posts(first: 100) {
                    nodes {
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        `,
    })

    const response = data.posts.nodes.map((post: Post) => post.slug)
    const slugs = await response.map((slug: string) => ({ params: { slug } }))

    return [{ slugs }]

    /* returns
    [{ params: { slug: 'blog-post-1' } }, { params: { slug: 'blog-post-2' } }...]
    */

}


async function getPost(params) {
    const { data } = await client.query({
     query: gql`
      query singlePost {
        post(id: "${params.slug}", idType: SLUG) {
          content
          categories {
            nodes {
              name
            }
          }
          featuredImage {
            node {
              sourceUrl
            }
          }
          postId
        }
      }
  `,
    })

    return {data.post}
}

export default async function PostPage({ params }) {
    const post = await getPost(params)

    return <Post post={post} />
}
```

Comment: you probably didn't generate paths in the correct way, this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/still-dew-2133e2) example may help you

Comment: thanks for the codesandbox! I got it to run locally, do you know why it does not run properly though if my setup is: `app/[slug].tsx`? I get the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slug')". But when in a `app/post/[slug]/` directory there is no error?

Comment: because in Next.js 13 `app` directory routes are defined using folders, and each folder has files to create the UI like `page.js` and `layout.js`, see the [documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/fundamentals#folders-and-files-inside-app) for more information

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the `params` key inside the object you return, you must only return the slug.

```js
export async function generateStaticParams() {
    const { data } = await client.query({
        query: gql`
            query getSlugs {
                posts(first: 100) {
                    nodes {
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        `,
    })

    const response = data.posts.nodes.map((post: Post) => post.slug)
    const slugs = response.map((slug: string) => ({ slug }))

    return slugs

    /* returns
        [{ slug: 'blog-post-1' }, { slug: 'blog-post-2' }...]
    */

}
```